# Updatepanel and timer not working in aside page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, timer

i have an aside tag `<aside class="right-side"></aside>` and i am filling it with the html from another page as below :

```
 function getContent(section) {
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "getContent.ashx",
                    contentType: "text/html;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: { section: section, opId:<%= op.id%> },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $(".right-side").html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
```

and the `getContent.ashx` is making a webclient request to display the page as below :

```
WebClient c = new WebClient()
content = c.DownloadString("page2.aspx");
context.Response.Write(content);
```

my problem is that in page2.aspx i am adding an Updatepanel and timer but they are not working and the timer does not fire, note that if i run the page directly without passing by the aside the timer trigger fires !!!

below is the update panel

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <!-- your content here, no timer -->
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel> 
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you call a webservice that downloads your page2 and then displays it in page1 by sending it back as a string? Why? What is the advantage of this construction?

Comment: yes exactly..it is used in a left side menu to display pages on the right side but i want the update panel to be working

Comment: Could you add the `response` of ajax call to getContent.ashx here?